# Error "Array to string conversion in" with mysqli bind_param

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

```
$searchTerm = isset($_GET['txtSearch']) ? $_GET['txtSearch'] : '';
$searchTerm = strtolower($searchTerm);
$searchTerm = strip_tags($searchTerm);
$searchTerm = trim($searchTerm," "); 

$keywords = explode(" ",$searchTerm); // break down search term into individual keywords

$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($keywords), '?'));
$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT * 
    FROM m_products
    WHERE product_title IN ($in);
SQL;
$statement = $con->prepare($select);
$statement->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($$keywords)), ...$keywords); //s = string, d = double, i = integer
$statement->execute();
```

I'm getting the following error from the above code:

> - Notice: Array to string conversion in
> - Notice: Undefined variable: Array in
> - Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Invalid type or no types specified in

How do I solve this error?

Comment: $statement->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($$keywords)), ...$keywords);  has a double $$ sign

Comment: Thanks I corrected the double $$ sign and now error is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i've told in the comments above:

```
$statement->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($$keywords)), ...$keywords); //s = string, d = double, i = integer
```

has a double $$ in the `count($$keywords))` remove one $ and the error should be resolved.